# Facebook OG Meta set by PHP not Being recognized

Tags: facebook

We have a website with facebook share, so we are setting OG tags by php

**LINK**

https://ph.mosaique.life/AizelleJoe/Goodpaying-Job-in-Japan-for-Filipinos

**FACEBOOK DEBUG TOOL**

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fph.mosaique.life%2FAizelleJoe%2FGoodpaying-Job-in-Japan-for-Filipinos

My issue is on our site the OG tags have content

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://ph.mosaique.life/Goodpaying-Job-in-Japan-for-Filipinos" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Good-paying Job in Japan for Filipinos" />
<meta property="og:description" content="If you are searching for a job not so miles away from the Philippines, Japan may be the best choice. " />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://mosaique.life/uploads/user-19/20181003084830572.png" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url " content="https://mosaique.life/uploads/user-19/20181003084830572.png" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="Good-paying Job in Japan for Filipinos" />
```

but when we use Facebook tool is is all empty

```
<meta property="og:url" content="">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta property="og:image" content="">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url " content="">
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="">
```

Comment: That is because you are not setting them in the request Facebook does to your server. Why is impossible for us to answer

Comment: What do you mean? Where we can set them ?

Comment: You set them in the HTML that you send back to Facebook when Facebook send the request to you. As you already linked to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fph.mosaique.life%2FAizelleJoe%2FGoodpaying-Job-in-Japan-for-Filipinos that is what you send back to Facebook right now

Comment: Sorry, I do not get it, how we can send it to facebook?

Comment: You output it in the response you send to Facebook

Comment: Ok then can you give me atleast some steps to fix it?

Comment: Well how about you give the _correct_ URL in the meta tags? You specified `https://ph.mosaique.life/Goodpaying-Job-in-Japan-for-Filipinos` there, which only results in a 404. The `/AizelleJoe/` part is missing.

Comment: Hi! Misorude! Where in part /AizelleJoe/ is missing?


down vote
favorite
We have a website with facebook share, so we are setting OG tags by php

LINK

https://ph.mosaique.life/AizelleJoe/Goodpaying-Job-in-Japan-for-Filipinos

FACEBOOK DEBUG TOOL

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fph.mosaique.life%2FAizelleJoe%2FGoodpaying-Job-in-Japan-for-Filipinos